# achartengine space between y-axis-title and border of graphview

Tags: axis, achartengine, space

I've created a chart with 2 lines and 2 y-axes (left and right)...but when I add the titles of the y-axes the letters like g,p,q are cut below...especially in the case of the right y-axis title...
Since the chartview matches the parent-view I would like to know if it's somehow possible to add a space between title and border?

thank you in advance

[image: Screenshot of the graph]

Comment: Please provide a screenshot such as we understand what you mean.

Comment: Try setMargins, it should work .

Comment: I already tried that...that does not work...it only changes the size of the chart...the titles remain at the same place :/

Comment: any idea?!? that would be great...

Comment: @Dan please give solution, I have same problem..
hey sebi have you solve it?